# Keyup not firing when keydown opens an alert

Tags: javascript, onkeydown, onkeyup

I have two event handlers, one for keydown and one for keyup.  The keydown event handler triggers an alert message, but this prevents the keyup event from firing.

You can see a very simple example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/boblauer/jaGwT/  When the keydown opens an alert, the keyup is not fired, but when an alert is not opened, the keyup is fired.  Here's the code from the jsfiddle:

```
var i = 0;
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (i++ % 2) alert('down');
    console.log('down');
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    alert('up');
    console.log('up');
});
```

I have a library that supports listening to multiple key combinations (such as 'd + f'), so when a key is pressed, I need to add it to a list of keys that are currently pressed, and when a key is released, I need to remove it from said list.  The problem I'm running to is, if I want an alert to show when d + f are pressed at the same time, my code to remove those keys from the 'currently pressed' list never fires, because my keyup handler is never called.

I can't think of a good work around to this problem.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's because `alert()` blocks - you shouldn't really design your site around using `alert()`... maybe roll-your-own or use some kind of dialog.

Comment: It also happens in other situations, such as tabbing onto a hyperlink and then hitting enter to open the link.  When that happens, the enter's keyup event is not fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alert prevents the event from happening. What you could do instead is trigger this function manually, because it happens anyways.

```
var keyupfunction = function(e){
    alert('up');
    console.log('up');
}

window.addEventListener('keyup', keyupfunction);

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (i++ % 2) alert('down');
    console.log('down');
    keyupfunction(e);
});
```

But really, you shouldn't be using alerts. It prevents these events, but who knows what else it might break. Use something custom instead.

Comment: The keyup doesn't necessarily follow the keydown event.  For example, I can press and hold ctrl, and then press another key without letting up on ctrl.

Comment: @BobLauer exactly, but in case of alert, there is no other way around it

Comment: Thank you, I never would have guessed that the alert was the problem.